# How connect Azure Machine Learning and Spark Streaming or Apache Storm

Tags: azure, hadoop, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there possibility to get stream from Spark Streaming or Apache Storm into Azure Machine Learning? In ***reader*** option there is an input to read data from Hive database
[image: hive]

but how to achive real time stream of data from Spark or Storm, for example ***Real-time fraud detection***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do real time Fraud detection typically you will create a Model on Azure ML, then publish that model to oWeb service, then on you Spark or Storm system you will call that Web service, in  sequence ( like payment happened on commercial sites for example), then you will get an immediate answer about the actual parameters you had sent in you web service call.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the desire to do this with Open Source Storm or Spark.

But I would like to offer the 100% Azure solution as well, because personally, I have found it a great way to quickly do many "easy" things with streaming data.

First, we have Service Buses, which can contain Event Hubs. An Event Hub is a well managed queue where one can stream data events into the Cloud. The queue has a pause, and rewind function, so if you need to modify your consumer, you can be assured to not lose data. You can also set the memory for the queue up to 7 days(this costs a bit more then say only storing data for 24 hours).

Once the data is in Event Hub, one can use Azure Stream Analytics in place of Storm or Spark to pop data from the queue. Stream Analytics uses SQL to query the queue. One attachs input and output data sources. Inputs can be event hubs, blobs, or even reference data sets. Outputs can include another Event Hub, azure blob, azure table, SQL databases, or even real time visualizations in PowerBI. Stream Analytics, has a scaling unit called "Streaming Units", where each unit equals 1 MB/s of bandwidth for processing. You only pay for the data you process, so if your stream goes quite, you don't pay, unlike using Storm or Spark in the cloud. Stream Analytics can even process messages with completely different formats, though I would recommend having at least a single field that has an ID for your message type. I basic Stream Analytics queries that stores your streaming data into blob might look like this

`Select * from EventHub into Blob`

In Stream Analytics, one can wrap an Azure Machine Learning web service as a function. This allows you to call AML and score you streaming data in real time. Stream Analytics is able to smartly create microbatches of AML calls, meaning it can score up to 200 decisions within a single AML call. Just make sure you have scaled your AML web service to keep up with the stream.

I hope this is seen as a genuine answer to the desire of the question, but in disclosure I do work for Microsoft on these products, but hope to make this more informative then sales pitch.